# GCD of a prime number and and increasing number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

I saw from [How to calculate "gcd product" $\operatorname{gcdp}(n,m)=\gcd(n,1)\gcd(n,2)\cdots\gcd(n,m)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807074/how-to-calculate-gcd-product-operatornamegcdpn-m-gcdn-1-gcdn-2-cdot)
that for  any prime number $n$, $$\gcd(n,1)\gcd(n,2)\cdots\gcd(n,m) =n^{\lfloor m/n\rfloor}.$$

I can see that the product must be some sort of power of $n$.

But I don't see why it's true.

PS: I'm not a number theory expert and this is not for a number theory class.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "power of $n$?"

Comment: Try computing the product by hand with $n=5$ and $m=23$. Once you understand what the gcd is doing, you'll see why the statement is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime. Given say $m > 0$, we are asked to calculate
$\gcd(p, 1)\gcd(p, 2) \dots  \gcd(p, m)$. Since $p$ is a prime and thus has only two divisors, for each factor $\gcd(p, k)$ there are only two cases:

- if $p$ does not divide $k$, then $\gcd(p, k) = 1$.
- if $p$ does divide $k$, then $\gcd(p, k) = p$.

With this observation, we see that
$$\gcd(p, 1)\gcd(p, 2) \dots  \gcd(p, m) = p^{\#\{k \in [m]: p\ \text{divides}\ k  \}}. $$

It remains to show that $\#\{k \in [m]: p\ \text{divides}\ k  \} = \lfloor m / p \rfloor$. In short, the left set is counting multiples of $p$ that are less than $m$. You should convince yourself that this floor counts the same thing.