# find a upper bound of a product of gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function

Let $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find a upper bound for

$\gcd(n,2^n) \gcd(n+1, 2^{n+1}) \cdots \gcd(n+2^k, 2^{n+2^k})$.

Note that in the upper bound, there should be no $n$, but having $k$ is fine.

Attempt:

$\gcd(n,2^n) \gcd(n+1, 2^{n+1}) \cdots \gcd(n+2^k, 2^{n+2^k}) 
\leq \gcd(n,  2^{n+2^k}) \gcd(n+1, 2^{n+2^k}) \cdots \gcd(n+2^k, 2^{n+2^k})
= \frac{\gcd(1,  2^{n+2^k}) \gcd(2, 2^{n+2^k}) \cdots \gcd(n+2^k, 2^{n+2^k})}{\gcd(1,  2^{n+2^k}) \gcd(2, 2^{n+2^k}) \cdots \gcd(n-1, 2^{n+2^k})}$

Then I tried to eliminate the $n's$ by using [How to calculate "gcd product" $\operatorname{gcdp}(n,m)=\gcd(n,1)\gcd(n,2)\cdots\gcd(n,m)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807074/how-to-calculate-gcd-product-operatornamegcdpn-m-gcdn-1-gcdn-2-cdot).

Then it just got really messy.

What I'm really trying to do is to find a bound without the $n$. But leaving $k$
is fine.

It would be even better to find the actually value...

Thank you.

Comment: Note if $n + 2^{k} = 2^{j}$ for some positive integer $j$, then since $n + 2^{k} \gt j$, we get  $\gcd(n + 2^{k}, 2^{n + 2^{k}}) = n + 2^{k}$. Thus, any general upper bound of your expression is $\ge n + 2^{k}$.

Comment: $gcd(n,2^n)$ is just the biggest factor $2^l$ that divides n. Therefore you simply count all $2^l$-factors between n and $n+2^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to note is that there is **no** upper bound in terms of $k$ only.

For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $n=2^N$ where we can choose $N$ to be as large as we like. Then the quantity that you are trying to bound contains the factor $$2^N=\gcd(2^N,2^{2^N})$$ independently of whatever $k$ is.